# Select from multiple tables mysql Java

Tags: java, mysql, select

How can I insert distinct movie titles to an Arraylist with a given theater city variable?

For example I want the Arraylist to be populated with all of the movie titles that in the showtimes table are linked to a theater id that its city is LA.

**showtimes** table

```
id  movieId theaterId 
1   1        1
2   1        1
3   1        2
4   1        2
5   2        2
6   2        2
7   1        3
8   4        1
```

**theaters** table

```
id city
1  LA
2  NY
2  NJ
```

**movies** table

```
id  title 
1   avengers  
2   matrix   
3   lotr
4   inception
```

Result Arraylist should be populated with : avengers and inception
because LA id is 1 which in the showtimes table leads to `movieId` *1,1,4*
and these `movieId` leads to the movies table title avengers and inception (avengers should be inserted only once (distinct))

Comment: Use a Map(String,List<String>)

Comment: where is the SQL query? What's your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it within the database via JDBC, e.g.

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT movies.title
    FROM
        showtimes
        ,theaters
        ,movies
    WHERE
        movies.id = showtimes.movieID
        AND showtimes.theatreID = theatre.id
        AND theatre.city = 'LA';
```

Then iterate the result set and add into your `ArrayList`